# Swift Package Manager, How to add a package as development dependency?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Is there a way, to add a spm package as development dependency?

For example, is there a way we can do some thing like, `developmentDependencies: { somePackage }`.

(like we can easily achieved in other package managers like npm, pub, etc?)

Comment: I think you want to edit the spm package while in an actual project instead of doing it stand alone. You can do this by cloning your repo inside your project. Then cloning your spm repo outside the project and dragging it into your actual xcode project. Then it will replace your spm package for a local package and you can do edits there.

Comment: @Wouter125 Thanks for the answer, i guess my question needed an example. What I meant, for example, if we want to use a "Lorem generation" package only in test(i.e. development stage). But we do not want to ship this package integrated into our app (i.e. production dependencies).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I can confirm<sup>1</sup> at as of Swift 5.2 this is possible. [SE-0226](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0226-package-manager-target-based-dep-resolution.md) defines "Target Based Dependency Resolution", which basically means that SPM will only download the dependencies that are actually required by the target(s) you use.

For example:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftlySearch",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SwiftlySearch",
            targets: ["SwiftlySearch"]
        ),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/nalexn/ViewInspector.git", from: "0.4.3")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SwiftlySearch",
            dependencies: []
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SwiftlySearchTests",
            dependencies: ["SwiftlySearch", "ViewInspector"]
        ),
    ]
)
```

This will only download ViewInspector for the target "SwiftlySearchTests", and *not* for the released library SwiftlySearch.

TL;DR: Just declare dependencies only on the targets that use them, SPM will figure out the rest.

---

<sup>1</sup> I just tested this using the built-in package manager in Xcode 11.6, which behaved as expected.

Answer (score -1):

No, there currently is not. It's something I've seen discussed a few times on the [Swift Evolution forums](https://forums.swift.org), it's something I'd like, and I actually thought I had seen some news about it happening, but alas, no.

The "best" way to get the same effect as of right now is to comment out your dev dependencies when doing release builds. There's a tool called [Rocket](https://github.com/shibapm/Rocket) that includes the hiding of dev dependencies as part of its release steps. I haven't used it, though, as I chose to write my own scripts instead. My example is my project [DiceKit](https://github.com/Samasaur1/DiceKit), where the [`Package.swift`](https://github.com/Samasaur1/DiceKit/blob/master/Package.swift) file does not include dev dependencies, and when my CI needs those dependencies, I run an [`include_dev_dependencies.py`](https://github.com/Samasaur1/DiceKit/blob/master/scripts/include_dev_dependencies.py) script before testing and a [`remove_dev_dependencies.py`](https://github.com/Samasaur1/DiceKit/blob/master/scripts/remove_dev_dependencies.py) after testing.

This approach is definitely not ideal, and may not work for you, but I hope you can figure something out. Good luck!

Comment: I came across this question the other day and put my head down in defeat and deleted my fairly related question. Since then, I have actually got this working without using any scripts like the above and verified the output binaries with `otool`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62882461/737234

Comment: @jordanperry That seems interesting (and I'd love to be able to remove my scripts), but I think that your solution doesn't include the dependency in your product, but still fetches it, while my way means that the dependencies are completely ignored unless you include them. I think they both have specific use cases, but I think the OP's question matches my situation.

Comment: your statement is valid. My solution still does fetch (and build), but makes sure it isn't included in the release binary. Hopefully still worth sharing.

Comment: I think so! (also, nice account icon!)

Answer (score -1):

```
.target(
    name: “MyDemoApp",
    dependencies: [
        .product(name: "jsonlogic", package: "json-logic-swift")
    ]
),
```

had to declare the import name as well as the package name

Comment: This is a good point.  When a package provides muliple products, you need this .product naming.  I spent hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score -1):

With simple package dependencies, where there is only one module in the package (like `SwiftlySearch` and `ViewInspector` in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63223261/1693173)) all you need is the `dependencies:` sections and name the packages in your target section.

However, some packages provide multiple products, such as **AWS Amplify** (or **AWS Core**).  They have many modules, so the `dependencies:` section is insufficient.

```
import Amplify
import AWSCognitoAuthPlugin
```

In this case, in addition to the package dependencies: section, you also need dependencies on each of the products in the target section.

For example, I have this package dependency in my `Package.swift` file:

```
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift", .upToNextMajor(from: "2.25.4"))
    ],
```

and I also need dependencies on the products used by my target:

```
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Amplify", package: "amplify-swift"),
                .product(name: "AWSCognitoAuthPlugin", package: "amplify-swift")
            ])
```

In this example I am using AWS Amplify product from my own Swift Package `MyPackage` (not an app).  My complete Package.swift with the package and product dependencies looks like this:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v16)  // requires iOS 16 minimum
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, making them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift", .upToNextMajor(from: "2.25.4"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Amplify", package: "amplify-swift"),
                .product(name: "AWSCognitoAuthPlugin", package: "amplify-swift")
            ])
    ]
)
```