# Swift Package Manager: Exclude from Release

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Let's say that I only wanted to link https://github.com/pmusolino/Wormholy to my iOS app on non-RELEASE configurations using SPM.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make Link optional
2. Update the `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` for `Release` to exclude the framework, e.g. `Wormholy*`